# why my contents are not getting loading when i come from some page and get loaded when i refresh it in jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I need help on the following. there are 3 pages 1st is static and second is dynamic based on that third is also dynamic.

When it navigates from 1 st to 2nd it get the content as displays it but when it navigates from 2nd to 3rd it unable to load the content. But when i refresh the page it loads the content. I am not able to get what's wrong in this. Could anyone help me on this?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var b_id = getUrlVars()["b_id"];
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/ajax_practice/php/get_categories.php?b_id=' + b_id,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function (data, status) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var output = "";
                    $(".main_category").append(output);
                    $(".main_category").listview("refresh");
                    output += "<li>";
                    output += "<a href='directory.html?c_id=" + item.id + "&b_id=" + b_id + "' data-transition='slide' rel='external'>";
                    output += item.category_name;
                    output += "</a>";
                    output += "</li>";
                    $(".main_category").append(output);
                    $(".main_category").listview("refresh");
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Html page

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <ul class="header_box" data-theme="d">
            <li>
                <select data-native-menu="false" name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu" data-theme="d">
                    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
                <select data-native-menu="false" name="selectmenu2" id="selectmenu2" data-theme="d">
                    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <img src="images/logo1.png"><span>www.justclick.co</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <select data-native-menu="false" name="selectmenu2" id="selectmenu3" data-theme="d">
                    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
                <select data-native-menu="false" name="selectmenu2" id="selectmenu4" data-theme="d">
                    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="header_search">
            <div class="search_input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="What ? e.g. Hotel" data-theme="d">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Where? eg. Area" data-theme="d">
            </div>
            <div class="search_button">
                <a>
                    <img src="images/search_button.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="header">
            <div class="service_heading">Business Information & Services</div>
        </div>
        <ul data-role="listview" class="main_category"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

php code

```
<?php header( 'Content-type: application/json'); 

    include 'connect.php'; 
    $b_id=$_GET[ 'b_id']; 
    $sql_select=mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM business_category WHERE b_id=$b_id") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $records=array(); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql_select)>0) { 
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_select)) { 
            $records[] = $row; 
        } 
        echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');'; 
    } else { 
        echo 'data not selected'; 
      } 
?>
```

I am not able to get the content of the page when i come from previous page but i get it when i refresh the page.Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

jQueryMobile uses by default an Ajax mechanism for transitions between pages. Note that when a new page is loaded through Ajax, the scripts and styles included inside the `head` tag are not loaded. jQueryMobile only loads the `body` element of the new pages and more specifically the `data-role="page"` element.

However when the page is loaded through HTTP then the scripts and styles inside the `head` tag are normally loaded. This explains why your page appears properly when opening the page directly.

In order to resolve your issue you have to perform the following actions:

- Replace `$(document).ready(function() {` with `$(document).on('pageinit', '#your-page-id', function() {`
- Move your second page's `script` from the `head` tag inside the `<div data-role="page">` or place the `script` inside a common JS file and load it inside the first page's `head` tag

I hope this helps.